# Как фильтры поменять на русский в angular kendo-treelist?

Tags: angular, kendo

Как в  kendo-treelist операторы в фильтре (`equal to`, `not equal to`, `is equal to null` и т.д.) поменять на русские `содержит`, `не содержит`, `эквивалентно`?

Answer (score 0):

> The localization script replaces the default messages in the widget
> prototype with their equivalent translations. The file has to be named
> by following the kendo.messages..js convention. A language
> code identifier list is available for free download from the Microsoft
> developer network website.

Перевод:

> Скрипт локализации замещает сообщения по умолчанию в прототипе виджета
> соответствующим переводом. Файл перевода должен иметь имя
> соответствующее следующему соглашению `kendo.messages.<language>.js`.
> Список языковых идентификаторов доступен для свободного скачивания с
> сети сайтов Microsoft для разработчиков.

[Сыль](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/localization)

Внутри файла перевод осуществляется по следующей схеме:

```
/* <Widget-name> messages */

if (kendo.ui.<Widget-name>) {
    kendo.ui.<Widget-name>.prototype.options.messages =
        $.extend(true, kendo.ui.<Widget-name>.prototype.options.messages,{
            "<message-name>": "<translation",
        //...
    });
}
```